# I've changed the bulb in my security light and now it won't go on ,why

Tags: lighting

Why won't my security light turn on after putting in a new bulb

Comment: What kind of bulb was in it before, and what kind of bulb are you installing now?

Comment: Security light? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If it is installed in a motion sensor that is controlled through a wall switch you may need to activate the switch once or twice to reset the sensor.

Also remember that the sensor has a photo cell that will prevent the light from going on in the daytime. To bypass this mode switch the light to "test" mode and it will work in daylight.